# Flutter prevent close dialog on back pressed

Tags: flutter

I am using the showDialog function to build a dialog box, but I need to avoid that when the user presses the back button, the dialog box does not close, this is my code:

```
showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,

      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Hello"),
          content: new SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog

            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

How can I get it to not close?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to enclose your AlertDialon on a `WillPopScope` like this:

```dart
showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,

      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: (){},
            child:AlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Hello"),
            content: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(),),
            actions: <Widget>[
              // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
              new FlatButton(
                child: new Text("Close"),
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        )
      },
    );
```

The `WillPopScope` provides you a `onWillPop` parameter, where you can pass a function of what you want when the child pop. In this case, the parameter receive an empty function so it wont pop.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it that way, but the dialogue keeps closing

Comment: Forget it, I had another error in my code haha ​​it works perfect thanks!

Comment: I would give you a 10000 reputation for this solution if I could! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 17):

You need to use a `WillPopScope`. It will use the function on `onWillPop` to determine if the dialog closes or not. In this case always false, so the user can't use the back button to close the dialog.

```
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    // return object of type Dialog
    return WillPopScope(
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Hello"),
        content: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog

          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text("Close"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        return false;
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also do it by setting `onWillPop: () => Future.value(false)` inside `WillPopScope`. Right now `onWillPop:(){}` as mentioned in Accepted answer gives warning.

**Warning Message:** *This function has a return type of 'Future', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.*

So, use `onWillPop: () => Future.value(false)` or `onWillPop: () async {return false;},` instead.

```
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: AlertDialog(
        ................
      ),
      onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Getx Dialog then use like this:

```
Get.defaultDialog(
      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      title: "",
       barrierDismissible: false,
      radius: 10,
      onWillPop: () => Future.value(false),
      content:Container());
```